# In org-mode, how to automatically turn of a certain minor mode for a particular file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am writing a table in org-mode that is broader than the screen. Visual-line minor mode is enabled per default, which is useful in most situations. However, visual-line mode wraps my broad table at the edge of the screen, which makes it unreadable. Therefore I would like to turn off visual line mode for this particular file.

The way I would preferably like to implement this is via a file header. Is this possible?

Comment: Check out file local variables and set `visual-line-mode` to `nil` -- here is a link to the manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think setting the file-local `visual-line-mode` variable will work. Typically (these days, at any rate) you need to use the `eval` pseudo-variable to enable or disable minor modes that way.

You can do this in the header:

```
# -*- eval: (visual-line-mode 0); -*-
```

or in a comment block at (generally) the end of the file:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (visual-line-mode 0)
# End:
```

Comment: Thank you! This isn't the org-mode specific solution that I was looking for, but it does the job perfectly well.